# How group List by key and transform the result

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following list and I need to transform it to get this result
**original list**

```
+----+--------------------+
| key|        email       |
+====+====================+
| 1  |    one@gmail.com   |
| 2  |    two@gmail.com   |
| 1  |   three@gmail.com  |
| 1  |    four@gmail.com  |
| 2  |    five@gmail.com  |
| 2  |    six@gmail.com   |
+----+----------------+-----
```

**New list** the mails concatenated with ***;***

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------+
| key|                       email                       |
+====+===================================================+
| 1  |    one@gmail.com;three@gmail.com;four@gmail.com   |
| 2  |    two@gmail.com;five@gmail.com;six@gmail.com     |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+
```

How can i accomplish this task with c# Linq? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
x.GroupBy(t => new {t.Id})
 .Select(t => new {
    Id = t.Key.Id,
    email = String.Join(", ", t.Select(p => p.Email).ToArray()) 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you have a class similar to this:

```
public class myEmails
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and a `List<myEmails>` that could be like this:

```
List<myEmails> emails = new List<myEmails>();
```

You could [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupBy%60%602);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) the `Key` value and then [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.Join);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) all strings (`Emails`) related to that `Key`, creating a new **`Dictionary<int, string>`** that contains all the Emails grouped by the given `Key`:

```
var emailsDictionary = emails
    .GroupBy(eml => eml.Key)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => string.Join(" ", grp.Select(eml => eml.Email)));
```

Test the result with:

```
emailsDictionary.ToList().ForEach(dict => Console.WriteLine($"{dict.Key}: {dict.Value}"));
```

It should give you:

```
1: one@gmail.com three@gmail.com four@gmail.com
2: two@gmail.com five@gmail.com six@gmail.com
```

As a note, if you're interested, you could also use [Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate%60%602);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `Join`, so this:

```
grp => string.Join(" ", grp.Select(eml => eml.Email))
```

could also be expressed as:

```
grp => grp.Aggregate("", (s, eml) => (eml.Email + " " + s))
```

Comment: I tested it and I get the result that I expected.  Finally I implemented a class instead of a dictionary.